# how many ways to make $k$ faces

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a set of $k$ closed curves (or just triangles) in the plane that cannot intersect. How many different ways can you make faces out of these lines? So if $k = 2$, there are two possibilities since you can have the closed curves separate or you can put one curve inside the other. Either way, there are two faces (other than the third unbounded face) induced by the curves. Similarly, I believe there 4 possible ways to have three faces with three closed curves. How can this value be expressed in terms of $k$? Sorry for the strange wording, I'm not entirely sure how to express the question.

Comment: How did you get 4 for $k=3$.

Comment: This is similar to the [Catalan numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) in the guise of the number of ways to match $k$ sets of parentheses, taking each pair of parentheses to be a loop. The Catalan numbers care about order in a way you do not.  They consider (())() different from ()(()), but for you there is just a single loop and two concentric loops.

Comment: @Umakant:  three concentric, two concentric plus one separate, three separate, one containing two separate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given an arrangement of $k$ closed curves, construct a rooted tree on $k+1$ vertices as follows: there is a vertex for each closed curve, and a root vertex corresponding to the entire plane (or a giant curve large enough to enclose all the $k$ given curves). Two vertices are connected if one of the two corresponding curves contains the other, but there is no third curve containing the inner one and contained in the outer one.

This correspondence gives a bijection between the number of "$k$-face" configurations you describe, and the number of rooted trees with $k+1$ vertices (equivalently, with $k$ edges). (The attached picture shows an example of this bijection when $k=4$.) No closed formula is known, but a lot of information can be found on [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A000081) for example.

[image]

Comment: The first comment in the OEIS entry specifically says this series solves the problem.